# Is it possible to transfer ownership of posts?

Tags: support

Say, I found an old good quality question, but the author of the post edited the question to add their answer. I could remove their answer and make a community wiki answer, but could I attribute the entire answer to the original author? I could do so by mentioning their name and giving credit, but is it possible to do this - where the author is actually attributed in the system and gets the deserved future reps?

---

Disputing duplicate: The above was just a example.  Another example would be where if you have two accounts used with specific tags(say one for [blender] and another for [vue.js]) and you answered one question with another account (which you didn't mean to), but the answer was accepted and upvoted multiple times - and now you'd like to transfer the ownership of that post from one account to another. To be clear, the question is

**Is it possible to transfer ownership of posts?**

Comment: An old thread with an answer in the wrong place offends some people's sense of good form, but it's doing no harm if matters are clear.

Comment: possible? of course... but it'll probably never happen for the purpose given. We regular users can't do it, neither can mods.

Comment: @KevinB Do you know for sure, mods can't do this?

Comment: [RyanM has previously also mentioned](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54754142#54754142) that something like this could be helpful when a user makes an edit to an existing answer that probably should have been it's own standalone post.

Comment: I disagree, there seems to be too many abuse vectors with this (patching which would be much work for the developers). If this is ever implemented it should be limited to moderators.

Comment: I have trouble with referring to this as "ownership". Once you commit it, it becomes community property. What you are essentially referring to here is changing the original creator, not the owner. If you approach it from that perspective, it just sounds like the wrong solution to a problem - the problem being someone making edits that are against the guidelines.

Comment: @Gimby It doesn't become community property. You  provide Stackexchange with the CC license, which doesn't grant ownership at all.  Just because someone can make derivative works doesn't mean you're not the original author, i.e., the owner. Why do you think reputation only goes to the original author and not the editors?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A tool exists that CMs have used in the past to change the post owner, but it would not be used for either of the situations you describe. It is only used on Meta on high-profile posts owned by SE employees and has only been [used a handful of times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338270/why-is-se-removing-links-and-community-ads-about-legal-issues#comment1126455_338270), ever.

See [When is it reasonable to change the owner of a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338305/323179)

Because the tool leaves no public log of what happened and could put words in people's mouths and could cause someone to lose reputation for something they didn't post, it's best that it stay this way.

We manage well enough with Community Wiki answers when quoting others' words. We have disassociation when it's best that nobody owns the post. And you're on your own for managing your own socks.

Comment: Thanks for the links and nice information. I only disagree with the part that this should not be used for any of the situations, I describe. - I specifically agree with this [linked answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338307/). If this leaves no public log, then that issue should be dealt with - the tool should be modified 1. to provide  public logs and 2. to be used [by mods](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/54754142#54754142)

Comment: @TheMaster if someone has multiple accounts IMO they should be entirely responsible for what each account posts and should not expect support in transferring posts between the two. What guarantee do the moderators and staff have that it's really a sock and not just a friend of the user who uses the same machine/ IP address? IMO it's just not worth it to provide this capability to users (on their own or via flags)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat The identity of users is irrelevant. If one account requests a post to be transferred, the receiving account accepts it, the reasoning provided is rational and there isn't any "obvious" foul play, then  such a request should be accepted by moderators. If not, rejected as per moderator discretion.

Comment: @TheMaster so you don't see any issues with that? Transferring ownership of posts implies transferring reputation from the votes on the post if it's not obvious. Why should this be this be something that shouldn't be relevant? Reputation is tied with the privilege system.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Like I said, if the reasoning is rational, such a request should be accepted.  I  don't see issues with this. In case of Sock puppets, not just the ip,  judging the rationale -like one account predominantly answered only in [blender] and other in [vue.js] -style of writing is exactly the same-  things like that..if it's just a one-off etc. In case of community wiki answers, it is obvious that the answer was moved from the original author and deserves credit. Like I said, moderator discretion. As you know, at least one mod RyanM came across a issue, where  this helps.

Comment: @TheMaster In the case of sock puppets is it really relevant to the community then which user owns the post? Wasting moderator time because "I want to maintain separation between the topics my accounts post on" doesn't seem like a valid reason for moderators to spend time on this. If they've posted with the wrong account so be it. The community wiki answers can potentially be considered.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Moderators do spend time on things that don't exactly benefit the community at large, but the individual(who is a part of the community). For eg, Requesting removal of inadvertent sensitive info leak,  Any disassociation request... 

Thank you for considering community wiki answers for this proposal.

Answer (score 15):

The best you can do is add your own community wiki answer and edit the question to remove their answer as it doesn't belong there. That way at least people can vote on whether the answer is a good one independently of the question.

The only way for someone to get reputation from an answer is for them to directly create that answer. You could also add a comment to the question and see if the OP responds and if they do, delete your wiki answer.